# Add hidden values inside an <select> tag

Tags: php, html

```
 <select name="Country" id="Country" style="width:200px;">
                        <option value="0">--Select Country--</option>
                        <?php 
                        $str_c="SELECT COUNTRY_CODE,COUNTRY_CODE_PARCELFORCE,COUNTRY_DESC FROM COUNTRYS";
                        $sql_c=mysql_query($str_c,$db) or die(mysql_error());
                         while($row_c = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_c)) { 
                                 $count_no++;
                             ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_CODE_PARCELFORCE'];?>"<?php if($row_c['COUNTRY_DESC']== $row['COUNTRY']) echo 'selected="selected"'?>><?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_DESC'];?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </select>
```

How can i add hidden variable inside the while loop for the value COUNTRY_CODE?Is it possible to add hidden value like `<input type="hidden" name='country_code' value="<?php echo $ro_c['COUNTRY_CODE']?>">`,Please help me...Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why would you need a hidden value?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a hidden value inside a `<select>` tag,however if you want to add a custom attribute to the `option` you can do like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_CODE_PARCELFORCE'];?>"<?php if($row_c['COUNTRY_DESC']== $row['COUNTRY']) echo 'selected="selected"'?> attribute1="<?php echo $row_c['CUSTOM_ATTR'];?>"><?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_DESC'];?></option>
```

To access the cutom attribute using Jquery use like this

```
$('#Country').change(function(){
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('attribute1'));
});
```

Comment: You should use `data` attributes if you want to use this method. Adding your own attributes is neither supported on all browsers, nor is is good practice (what happens when the next version of a browser comes out and uses that attribute for something?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this. I would suggest doing the while loop outside of the select code.

So you get

```
<?php
// sql stuff
$options = '';
$hidden = '';
while($row_c = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_c)){
  $count_no++;
  $options .= "<option value="<?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_CODE_PARCELFORCE'];?>"<?php if($row_c['COUNTRY_DESC']== $row['COUNTRY']) echo 'selected="selected"'?>><?php echo $row_c['COUNTRY_DESC'];?></option>"
  $hidden .= "<input type="hidden" name='country_code' value="<?php echo $ro_c['COUNTRY_CODE']?>">";
}

// now the select
?>
<select>
  <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
<!-- hidden values -->
<?php echo $hidden; ?>
```

Your comment says that it is for validation purposes. I can't think of a reason you'd ever need to do this for validation. If they're already stored in the database then you should do a validation lookup against the database once the form has been posted/submitted.

Otherwise, use @ubercooluk's method (but keep in mind my comment).

Comment: i just want to validate some departments based on the countries  by using the COUNTRY_CODE of the select query..